# Prove that $n ≤ d + 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-geometry

Let $n$ points $x_1, . . . , x_n$ lying on a unit sphere $S^{d-1} \subset R^d$
(with center in the origin) are such that the angle between any two of them is the same, that is,$<x_i
, x_j>$ does not
depend on $i \neq j ∈ [n]$. Prove that $n ≤ d + 1$.

This the numerical I am trying to solve. But the problem I am facing is that I cannot imagine how to take n points so that they all have the same angle. I do think I can solve it using a gram matrix of points  $x_1, . . . , x_n$ but somehow I am not able to implement it.
Could you please help me to solve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/555278/42969

Comment: This is false. We can take three points on $S^1$ that are each $120^{\circ}$ apart.

Comment: I'm confused about your bound: don't the 3 vertices of an equilateral triangle inscribed in $S^1$ have this property, yet $3 \not\le 1 + 1$?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the link. It is really helpful.

Comment: @JohnDouma Ah! I see your point. yeah, you are right though.

Answer (score 1):

Consider  the Gram matrix of $d+2$ distinct unit vectors $v_1\ldots,v_{d+2}$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$:

$$G_{ij}=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle.$$

Assume $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle =\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x, \text{ if } i\neq j \\
1, \text{  if } i=j
\end{array}\right. $

Since $v_i\neq v_j$, we have $x<1$.

Notice that $G_{d+2\times d+2}=(1-x)Id_{d+2\times d+2}+xA_{d+2\times d+2}$, where $A_{ij}=1$ for every $i,j$.

So the spectrum of $G_{d+2\times d+2}$ is $\ \ (1-x)+x(d+2),\ \stackrel{d+1 \text{ times}}{\overbrace{1-x,\ldots, 1-x}}$.

The rank of $G$ is at most $d$, since $v_1,\ldots, v_{d+2}\in \mathbb{R}^d$. So the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ of $G$ is at least two.

Notice that the only value of $x$ that forces $G$ to be singular satisfies $(1-x)+x(d+2)=0$, but the multiplicity of $(1-x)+x(d+2)$ is one. Absurd.

There are no $d+2$ distinct unit vectors of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the same angle between any two of them.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about the dimension of the sphere. I have edited the question

Comment: I actually didn't get the part of your answer from the part where you mentioned the multiplicity of the Eigen value 0 is 2

Comment: @Violet The rank of the Gram matrix coincides with the dimension of the subspace spanned by the vectors. In our case the dimension is at most , since the vectors belong to $\mathbb{R}^d$. So the dimension of the kernel is at least 2. Check the section "other properties" of the wikipedia page: Gram matrix.