# Maximum number of unit vectors with pairwise modulus-equal inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Fix $\alpha\in [0, 1)$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there exists a set of complex vectors $\{v_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}\subseteq \mathbb{C}^m$ that satisfies $\langle\, v_i \,,\, v_i\,\rangle = 1$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$ and $\big\vert\, \langle\, v_i \,,\, v_j\,\rangle \,\big\vert = \alpha$ for all different pairs of $1\leq i, j\leq n$. Can we find the least upper bound for $n$ in terms of $m$ and $\alpha$?

When $\alpha=0$, one obvious example is the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^m$. In general, the upper bound could be larger than $m+1$ based on [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31436) from **MO**. Unfortunately, I cannot find ideas from that post helpful. Any hints will be appreciated.

**Update**: this question is also related to [SIC-POVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIC-POVM), a topic that is currently being actively researched

Comment: "When $\alpha=0$, one obvious example is the union of the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^m$ and the zero vector in $\mathbb{C}^m$". Doesn't the zero vector violate your $\langle v_i, v_i\rangle = 1$ requirement?

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555278/assume-that-there-are-n1-vectors-of-dimension-n-and-all-angles-of-any-two-v answer your question?

Comment: @jwhite Thanks for pointing it out. That is such a silly mistake...

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for letting me such an interesting post. However, I believe answers in your link, especially the one written by *Glen*, provides an example that verifies the answer in the **MO** link in my post. Although vectors in the question in your link are presumably in $\mathbb{R}^2$, as *MVG* mentioned, in the case when $n=m+1$, this could be done by using simplicial geometry, but not necessarily for the general case.

Comment: I don't see where either answer makes the assumption that we're in ${\bf R}^2$. It seems to me that they prove that in ${\bf R}^n$, you can't have more than $m+1$ vectors. Isn't that what you want to know?

Comment: Simul-posted to MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462021/maximum-number-of-unit-vectors-with-pairwise-modulus-equal-inner-product without informing either site. DON'T DO THAT!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very difficult problem in general. The [Welch bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch_bounds) provide a set of lower bounds on $\alpha$ in terms of the parameters $n,m$ (the standard formulation has $m$ and $n$ switched from yours). The simplex set is one specific solution. More generally what you are looking for is an equiangular tight frame.

Comment: I suppose you are referring to the paper *Lower Bounds on the Maximum Cross Correlation of Signals* written by **L. E. Welch**. According to that paper, indeed we can tell $\alpha^4 \geq \dfrac{2n^2}{d(d+1)}$, but not much about the upper bound for $n$. May I ask if there is another easier version of this question, beside the simplex set one?

Comment: Well, this is an upper bound on $n$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $d.$ In general, the bound on the $2k$th moment is the tightest one if we have $n=O(d^k)$ vectors. And, no there is really no simpler solution that I am aware of